# How to implement pending data binding in sapui5 (declarative)?

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

Quite often it is required to implement some controls in one view that depend on each other.

For example:

A country select box and depending on the selection (pleas also think of the initial selection) another select box will show a list of regions.

I would prefer a declarative solution, but seems not possible.
I also would avoid using control ids, because this seems not usable if such a dependency is used inside a collection (there you will have dynamic ids...).

My current solution works like this:

```
var oCountry = new sap.m.Select({
    name : "Country",
    selectedKey : "{model>/CountryKey}",
    items : {
        path : "otherModel>/CountrySet",
        template : new sap.ui.core.Item({text : "{otherModel>CountryName}", key : "{otherModel>CountryKey}"})
    },
});

var oRegionTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({text : "{otherModel>RegionName}", key : "{otherModel>RegionKey}"})

var oCountry = new sap.m.Select({
    name : "Region",
    selectedKey : "{model>/Region}",
    enabled : {
        path : "model>/CountryKey",
        formatter : function(oValue) {
            if (oValue===undefined || oValue === null) {
                return false;
            }
            var that = this;
            that.bindAggregation("items", "otherModel>/CountrySet('"+oValue+"')/RegionSet", oRegionTemplate);
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

There a property is bound to the country selection and a formatter is "misused" to bind the aggregation.

Is there any "cleaner" solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Use the onChange event of the Region select box. When it changes, rebind the aggregation for the countries using the current region value in the filter.
Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, UI5 does not support declarative binding in the filters. (Any core developer reading this?)

Comment: But this will not work for an initial value in the first select box. The "onChange" will be triggered if user selects something but not during first load of the control.

Comment: You are right. But since the user did not select Region, maybe you don't need to set the binding for the countries initially. Depends on the situation really.

Comment: @user3783327 You have to call the `fireChange` function of the country in your `onBindingChange` function of your view. This means when user enter to your object page and an object is bound to your view, then you have to extract the country value and use that value to filter the values in region element.